# tkinter entry assistance Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am a GUI that uses an entry field, I want the delete button to delete the end character held in the index within the entry field. I have managed to get my clear button working, by doing the following

```
entry.delete(0, END) #Deletes all values in the entry field
```

I thought I could just do the following to delete the end item but it does not work. Any ideas

```
entry.delete(END)
```

I replace 'END' above with a number it will delete that number, but I'm sure there must be a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the length of the text and use it as the start of the range:

```
start = len(entry.get()) - 1
entry.delete(start, END)
```